# VS Code - Move the cursor between 'k' and 'O' in the word "stackOverflow"

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I want to move the cursor in to next Uppercase letter in a word like between `e` and `C` in the word `googleChrome` with a keyboard shortcut. We all tend to use variables with two words as `twoWords` instead of `two_words`. So, It would be really helpful if we can move the cursor between the word without pressing the arrow key a lot of times.

In Sublime Text, I can use `Alt + Right` or `Alt + Left` to do that. But in Visual Studio Code, I am not able to use `Alt + Right` or `Alt + Left` shorcut to do that.

I would also like to know how to convert `two_words` to `twoWords` with a shortcut in Visual Studio Code if it is possible.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can try using the [Sublime Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings) if that's what you're comfortable with. And for converting case of a variable, again what you try is [Case Converter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.CaseConverter) as VS-Code has built-in support for transforming to snake case but not camel case.

Comment: you can look if `Text Manipulator` by Adam Walzer does what you want in renaming

Comment: I found out the answer for that second question ! Pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P` which brings up the command pallette, and typing in `Transform to snake case` in the command pallette. You can set any keybinding for that by adding this to your keybindings.json file and replacing the `ctrl+k ctrl+;` to any shortcut you would like
`{"key": "ctrl+k ctrl+;","command": "editor.action.transformToSnakecase"}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and search for: "cursorWordPartLeft" and "cursorWordPartRight" and bind them to any key that you want. They should do what you want

Mac example of swapping the word and word part behaviors:

[image: screenshot of the Keyboard Shortcuts settings panel with keys reassigned]

Answer (score -1):

this should do the work

```
Control + Option + Arrow [left/right]
```